# Best time series methods to forecast 1 value, with 23 previous values?

Tags: r, time-series, assets, forecasting

I face the following problem: I have a bunch of data values that consists of 23 values (supposed to have 1 value for each hour) and I'm asked to forecast the 24th value of the serie. These 23values are not supposed, to be periodic or seasonality, or monthly etc..., as they are said to reprensent the value of some financial assets through the time.

For the moment I've tried to forecast with the TBATS methods in R Studio but it ended really bad.

Now, I'm going to use some others forecasting methods as: ARIMA/SARIME; VAR; Exponential smoothing etcc.... Do you guys have any idea what would be the most relevant method for this kind of problem ?

I'm asking some advice instead of testing them all. I should mention that i'm using R studio as a lot of these methods are already implemented in it.

Thank you in advance for any kind of help ! Ps: I should mention that the values of my data are really closed to 0, example of the first 14th values: [image]

I already tried the TBATS method with default value, as in this tutorial: https://www.projectpro.io/recipes/what-is-tbats-model-time-series-use-it
Example with TBATS method of a forecast: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBW3I.png

Comment: Now that you're considering ARIMA/SARIME, try LSTM as well.

Comment: Your time series are very short. Trying out more and more complex time series methods is not very likely to give better results. Try simpler methods instead. And have realistic expectations about how predictable the hourly changes of financial assets are.

Comment: @dipetkov Thanks for this answer, what name of simpler methods can you suggest please ? I'm not very aware of the forecasting fields for time series, so any name could help me a lot !

Comment: As simple as predicting the previous or the average of the last *k* values. A sequence of 23 numbers that even by your own description contain no patterns hardly qualifies as a time series. You might find this [Cross Validated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/222179/237901) relevant.